# Wordpress: Use bootstrap in the post

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an external theme on my wordpress page. I connected bootstrap to my project. But is it any posibility to use bootstrap abilities while writing new posts ? Because the wordpress does not recognize this code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it just "col" or col-xx-xx" ? it has to be something like "col-md-6" according to bootstrap grid system.

Comment: @JokerFan , it is just an working example from bootstrap oficial page, which MUST work.

Comment: have you added bootstrap CDN and other stuff